# How to remove all special characters except for underscore between two words in java?

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I want to remove all special characters from the string object below with some characters except for _(underscore) between two words in java ?

**my sample data would be**

a = *OIL~
b = OIL_GAS_
c = *OIL_GAS$
b = *OIL_GAS*

**This is the output I'm expecting:**

OIL
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS

I already have this  `String str1= s.replaceAll("(\\W)*", "");` 
And I could remove all special characters.  If any one could help me update my code How to remove all special characters except for underscore between two words

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Try `s.replaceAll("(\\p{L}_)(?=\\p{L})|\\W", "$1");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your answer, could you please explain it to me please ! what does it mean  p{L} !!

Comment: `\p{L}` matches letters. Did you mean the `_` between letters should stay?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `_` between ** two words** should stay

Comment: So, what is a word for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Probably means whether a space is replaced by a "_".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that what i mean TEST_TEST

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew another example if i have this data  `_OIL_GAS$`  output expecting is  `OIL_GAS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RegEx [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `[^\p{Alnum}_]|^_|_$` meets your requirement.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(
                    "OIL~", 
                    "_OIL_GAS",
                    "OIL_GAS_", 
                    "_OIL_GAS_",
                    "*OIL_GAS$", 
                    "OIL_GAS"
                ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}_]|^_|_$", "")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
OIL
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS
OIL_GAS
```

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aBAG25/1):**

[image]

**Note:** As you must have already understood from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\p{Alnum}` is same as `A-Za-z0-9`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `s.replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9_]", "");`

Basically anything that is not a letter, number or underscore. If you don't want to include numbers try `[^A-Z_]`

Update:

```
(?!_|^w)[^a-zA-Z]*|^_+|[^a-zA-Z]*(?=_|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/SZ8zGb/1

Comment: Thank for you answer, but its not work with this example `$OIL_GAS_` outpout exceptiong is `OIL_GAS`

Comment: Ok, after some searching myself i found this and had some success with removing leading and trailing underscores too. It also seems to remove only one underscore in case you have two in a row. Can you try:      (?!_|^w)[^a-zA-Z]*|^_+|[^a-zA-Z]*(?=_|$)

Answer (score 0):

Your code
String str1= s.replaceAll("(\W)*", "");
is already ok for your use case. this will remove special characters except underscore